# NullPointerException в render Sprite

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Прекрасно понимаю,что за ошибка,но не могу понять, почему возникает:
в классе `public class ResourseLoader`

```
atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("texture/texture.pack"), true);
background = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("background"));
```

текстуры запаковал,все в папке имеется
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в классе screen

```
  game.batch.draw(ResourseLoader.background,0,0,1920, 1080);
```

и тут вылетает ошибка

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.draw(SpriteBatch.java:598)
at upwardteam.pavel.game.MainMenuScreen.render(MainMenuScreen.java:155)
```

Comment: обычно бывает полезно проверить ВСЕ объекты в строке и убедиться что каждый из них инициализирован

Comment: @iamthevoid
  game.batch.draw(ResourseLoader.background,0,0,1920, 1080);

нажимаю на background и меня перекидывает в класс где я инициализировал

Comment: там есть еще game, batch, да и background может быть инициализирован неправильно. Увы, но большинство ошибок - дело наших собственных рук, проверять надо скрупулёзно

Comment: я понял, а вообще логика отрисовки верна?

Answer (score 2):

Вместо background = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("background")) попробуйте вставить background = new Sprite("какая-нибудь другая текстура"), если запустится - значит проблема в вашем атласе.

Если ошибка не исчезнет - начните проверять поочередно ваш SpriteBatch, Сцену и другие элементы, которые используете в вашем проекте. Возможно, где-то просто объявили переменную, но конструктор не добавили, и, следовательно, идет ссылка на null Объект.